# Variables not changing in c++

Tags: c++, string, integer

I am new to c++ so I don’t know much.
this is a program that gets the input from the user and changes the **Player Position variable (pp for short)**.

Then it changes the screen depending on the player position variable and prints it.

Here it is so far:

‘’’

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// main
int main() {
  // variables
  string scr = ". ";

  string grd = "0 ";

  string plr = "1 ";

  int pp = 0;
  
  string p11 = scr;
  string p12 = scr;
  string p13 = scr;
  string p14 = scr;
  string p15 = scr;
  
  string p21 = scr;
  string p22 = scr;
  string p23 = scr;
  string p24 = scr;
  string p25 = scr;

  string p31 = scr;
  string p32 = scr;
  string p33 = scr;
  string p34 = scr;
  string p35 = scr;

  string p41 = scr;
  string p42 = scr;
  string p43 = scr;
  string p44 = scr;
  string p45 = scr;

  string p51 = scr;
  string p52 = scr;
  string p53 = scr;
  string p54 = scr;
  string p55 = scr;

  while(true){
    // "clearing" the console
    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" << endl;
    
    // printing screen variables to the console
    cout << p11 << p12 << p13 << p14 << p15 << endl;
    cout << p21 << p22 << p23 << p24 << p25 << endl;
    cout << p31 << p32 << p33 << p34 << p35 << endl;
    cout << p41 << p42 << p43 << p44 << p45 << endl;
    cout << p51 << p52 << p53 << p54 << p55 << endl;

    // check for user input
    string input;
    
    cin >> input;
    
    if(input == "a"){
      pp = pp - 1;
    }
    
    if(input == "d"){
      pp = pp + 1;
    }

    // checking if the number is too large
    if(pp < -2){
      pp == -2;
    }

    if(pp > 2){
      pp == 2;
    }
    
    // moving the player
    if(pp == -2){
      p51 == plr;
    }else{
      p51 == scr;
    }

    if(pp == -1){
      p52 == plr;
    }else{
      p52 == scr;
    }

    if(pp == 0){
      p53 == plr;
    }else{
      p53 == scr;
    }

    if(pp == 1){
      p54 == plr;
    }else{
      p54 == scr;
    }

    if(pp == 2){
      p55 == plr;
    }else{
      p55 == scr;
    }
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

‘’’
**However**
The screen does not seem to change when I enter the string needed. I don’t know much in c++, I’m just applying knowledge and converting my game in python to c++.

Maybe I’m being really dumb, but if anyone knows how then that would be a big help.

Comment: Please read up on the difference between `=`  and `==`.

Comment: `pp == 2` and the like might not have the intended effect...

Comment: Enable warnings in your compiler, it can detect these mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

Around your 3rd if-statement, you've got equality operators instead of assignments!

```
// checking if the number is too large
if(pp < -2){
  pp == -2; // <-- HERE: This expression returns a Boolean!
            //           Doesn't do anything to 'pp'
}
```

Instead, it should be:

```
// checking if the number is too large
if(pp < -2){
  pp = -2;
}
```